Scala UDF with long running initialization
I have a scala UDF which functionally works, but slower than it should be.
It is a function that looks up location from an IP addresses. This uses a relatively large database (200+ MB), which I suspect is initialized for every lookup in a dataframe.
The function looks like this:
import com.ip2location

val ip2location = (ip: String) => {
  val loc = new com.ip2location.IP2Location
  loc.Open("///Volumes/.../ip2location/IPV6-COUNTRY-REGION-CITY.BIN")
  val rec = loc.IPQuery(ip)
  
  Map(
    "countryShort" -> rec.getCountryShort,
    "countryLong" -> rec.getCountryLong,
    "city" -> rec.getCity,
    "region" -> rec.getRegion
  )
}

spark.udf.register("ip2location", ip2location)

Specifically it is this line that is of concern loc.Open("///Volumes/.../ip2location/IPV6-COUNTRY-REGION-CITY.BIN")
I have tried varies ways of broadcasting loc, broadcasting the contents of the large file as a byte array or using an object with a lazy variable. All of these result in serialization errors - I suppose when Spark attempts to serialize the contents and distribute it to workers.
It could be used like this:
select
  `visitor_identifier`,
  `ip_address`,
  ip2location(`ip_address`) as `location`
from 
  `xyz`

Which again would return something like this:



visitor_identifier
ip_address
location




abc
194.182.29.100
{"countryShort":"DK","countryLong":"Denmark","city":"Odense","region":"Syddanmark"}



Any ideas?

Perhaps you can refactor your code to use mapPartitions() function which would allow you to initialize your connection once per Spark partition?

I would really like for this to work as a UDF, but your suggestion might be a solution to this.

You can consider loading the file into driver memory, convert it into dataframe, broadcast explicitly and use map to fetch values, or use a join with broadcast hint

Try creating a stateful static Function object that performs the initialisation:
// Read and broadcast the bin file.
val broadcastedDbBin: Broadcast[Array[Byte]] = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(dbBin)

object QueryIP2Location extends Function1[String, Map[String, Any]] {
  // Parse the database, initialise the indexes once per each JVM in the cluster.
  val loc = new IP2Location()
  loc.Open(broadcastedDbBin.value)

  def apply(ip: String) = {
    val rec = loc.IPQuery(ip)
    Map(
      "countryShort" -> rec.getCountryShort,
      "countryLong" -> rec.getCountryLong,
      "city" -> rec.getCity,
      "region" -> rec.getRegion
    )
  }
}


spark.udf.register("ip2location", QueryIP2Location.apply(_))


This is an analog of C++ local static variables.
Ideally, you'd want to broadcast the initialised (opened, with indexes read et cetera) instance of IP2Location; however, the issue is that IP2Location class is not serialisable and does not provide access methods that could allow custom serialisation to work. If the static variable would not work, you can contact the library's authors and ask to make it serialisable. I don't see a reason why it can't be.
For more information see IP2Location source code and How to serialize a non-serializable in Java? and Scala equivalent of C++ static variable in a function thread.

Just giving it as an answer so that it will help the community to find better solution.
Here is the sample code.
//import com.ip2location.IP2Location


val ipLocationRDD = ipdf.rdd.mapPartitions(iter => {
// val loc = new IP2Location()
// loc.Open("///Volumes/.../ip2location/IPV6-COUNTRY-REGION-CITY.BIN")
  
  val results = iter.map { ip =>
    //val rec = loc.IPQuery(ip)
    val location = Row(
    ip.get(0),
    "rec.getCountryShort",
    "rec.getCountryLong",
    "rec.getCity",
    "rec.getRegion"
  )
    location
  }
  
  results
})

And creating dataframe out of it.
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = StructType(
  List(
    StructField("ip", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("countryShort", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("countryLong", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("city", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("region", StringType, nullable = true)
  )
)

val ipLocationDF = spark.createDataFrame(ipLocationRDD,schema)
ipLocationDF.show(truncate = false)

Here, i have created a sample with random strings you use actual values.
Output:
+-----------+-------------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+
|ip         |countryShort       |countryLong       |city       |region       |
+-----------+-------------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+
|192.168.1.1|rec.getCountryShort|rec.getCountryLong|rec.getCity|rec.getRegion|
|10.0.0.1   |rec.getCountryShort|rec.getCountryLong|rec.getCity|rec.getRegion|
|172.16.0.1 |rec.getCountryShort|rec.getCountryLong|rec.getCity|rec.getRegion|
+-----------+-------------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+

import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(ip,StringType,true),StructField(countryShort,StringType,true),StructField(countryLong,StringType,true),StructField(city,StringType,true),StructField(region,StringType,true))
ipLocationDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ip: string, countryShort: string ... 3 more fields]


I am confused by your response. It's not an answer... how is creating a dataframe with hard coded values supposed to help?

It may help the community regarding this issue. Also please add your solution as answer.

There is no solution yet.

Are you using above code. What is the error you facing? Please replace the hard code values with you ip values and try.
